# Как вывести 30 таблиц, в которых будет содержаться 30 полей?

Tags: php, pdo

Как вывести 30 таблиц, в которых будет содержаться 30 полей? То есть имеем 1 таблицу в бд с 30 полями и на странице выводим 30 таблиц, вывод - 1 таблица содержит 2 ячейки `Заголовок столбца` и `значение столбца`. Выходит, что нужно 30 таблиц таких.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37112/discussion-on-question-by----30-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в каждом запросе используется одна и таже таблица.
Исходя из этого, делаю вывод что надо вывести на страницу данные из таблицы tovars, или не так?

**UPDATE 20160316145310**
С учётом вашего комментария. Это набросок. Детали сами поправьте.

```
<div class="ok">
    <?
    // массив названия полей
    $fields = [
        'id',
        'oblastnazn',
        'proizvoditel'
    ];
    $s = "SELECT %s FROM tovars";
    $sql = sprintf($s, implode(',', $fields));
    /** @var PDOStatement $stmt */
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);

    $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            print "<div class='tab'>";
            print "<table>";
            print "<thead>";
            print "<tr>";
            print "<th>$field</th>";
            print "</tr>";
            print "</thead>";
            print "<tr>";
            print "<td class='chenge' >";
            print $row[$field];
            print "</td></tr></table></div>";

        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

P.s. вообще не стоит верстать такие таблицы.

Comment: В вашем случае получится одна таблица, а мне нужно 30 таблиц. Для понимания всех я объясню зачем мне это, у меня есть одна таблица на странице она состоит из 30 полей и таблица не помещается на экране, чтобы решить проблему, мне нужно 30 таблиц которые содержат поля из 1 таблицы БД!!! и выводятся как одна большая таблица состоящая в структуре одной таблицы. Помимо таблицы у меня есть два div блока на которые написаны свойства CSS с помощью всего это у меня помещается таблица одна большая таблица которая состоит из 30 таблиц. PS: В БД 1 таблица хранит 30 полей.

Comment: @Элиот 1) Данные все в одной таблице бд?  2) Вам что ли нужно вывести данные для чтения сверху-вниз, а не слева-направо ?

Comment: 1) Все данные хранятся у меня в одной таблице в БД, 2) Смотрите пост, добавил картинку для ясности. По картинке если судить каждая ячейка это отдельная таблица.

Comment: @Элиот, а точно нужно чтобы _каждая ячейка_ была таблицей?

Comment: @Grundy, для полного уточнения будет использовать две ячейки. 1) название столбца 2) значение столбца. это все выходит в 1 таблицу.

Comment: @zenith, сделали так как и думал, замечательно! Один вопрос чтобы столбцы обозначались по русски что нужно сделать ?